# Cannot pass values from HTML to php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying top pass a value to php and run a function. But I can not get it to work?

```
 <form action="" method="post">
    Name: 
    <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>

<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    $folder = htmlentities($_POST['val1']); 
}
if( isset($folder) ) {
//do something with $folder
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: @AwladLiton there will be no error - just `isset($_POST['submit'])` always returns `False`

Comment: yah that is true but OP should clearify in the question that there is no error :)

Comment: @AwladLiton: I'm getting no error. nothing is happening. The input text goes blank after I hit the submit button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `name` to your `submit` if you wan't to check for it's existence in `$_POST`:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></input>
```

Comment: +1 Worth noting that not all browser versions will post a submit button value; so it's sometimes best to post a hidden value and check for that. Best to actually use a token generated by the server and store in user session then verify that the token matches the contents of the session to protect against CSRF.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: thanks. that did not work. I'm getting no response when I run the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
```

Due to the fact that your submit element does not have a name (as pointed out by @ElmoVanKielmo )

The original way I proposed is to try validating your val1 field:

```
if( isset( $_POST['val1'] ) ){
```

Or you can add the name attribute to your submit.

Comment: This is walking around the problem and not solving it.

Comment: Why would I get a downvote? The fact that I didn't mention the submit not having a name doesn't make my answer wrong.

Comment: Added to the answer so it shows what the real error is as mentioned by @ElmoVanKielmo